# Can not decrease product quantity in checkout cart page - Magento 1.9.2.4 ?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have to click the minus option quantity is decreased 0. In quantity is fixed 1 and not decreased 0. Please find my screenshots.https://prnt.sc/jf970j.I have smart wave and Porto theme. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear to I fully understand. What I understand is you want minimum 1 in qty box when user click minus(-). If I'm right then please find below code in porto theme JS file:

```
$(".table_qty_dec").unbind('click').click(function(){
    if($(this).parent().children(".qty").is(':enabled'))
        $(this).parent().children(".qty").val(($(this).parent().children(".qty").val()-1 > 0)?($(this).parent().children(".qty").val() - 1) : 0);
});
```

And replace above code with below code:

```
$(".table_qty_dec").unbind('click').click(function(){
    if($(this).parent().children(".qty").is(':enabled'))
        $(this).parent().children(".qty").val(($(this).parent().children(".qty").val()-1 > 1)?($(this).parent().children(".qty").val() - 1) : 1);
});
```

Comment: Hi @ Jignesh Baldha, Thank you. It is working.